# Do cucumbers inhibit spice and why?

Tags: flavor, spicy-hot, cucumbers

Part of my lunch included cucumbers. I noticed a pepper grinder nearby and thought I would put pepper on my cucumber. When I tried it, it did not feel spicy. Does cucumber inhibit spice? If it does, is it because a cucumber is 96% water?

Comment: …or maybe the pepper was a year old or more & had lost all its punch & aroma.

Comment: @Tetsujin I tried it without cucumber and it was spicy.

Comment: You're saying that pure pepper tasted more strongly of pepper than pepper mixed with something else did?

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.

Any food eaten together with any spice will "reduce" the flavor of that spice due to dilution with other flavors. Cucumbers are not special in this regard.